# Excel - Extracting data if a cell contains a text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have created an example image of what I am trying to do.

I want cells r3 to R11 to add up the any hours that in that row but holiday hours only.

Can anyone help? thank you

[image]

Comment: You show the values which you need... but it would be nice to explain how they were obtained.

Comment: Thank you,  

The rota is manually entered for the month. The column to the right of each day are hours entered manually based on length of shift so it keeps a total of the cost of hours that day. As holiday is a cost too I have kept holiday hours in the same box. This is all done simply with the sum function. 

What I am looking to do, is have a box on the right that purely extracts the hours that are holiday each week. 

Many Thanks for your help,

Comment: Please be more detailed. Like "I need to obtain value ... in a cell ... which is a sum of cells ... values because these cells ...".

Comment: Hi Akina, 

I will try and redo the image. I snipped it to remove any named data but will try and amend to be more specific, one moment, thank you.

Comment: I have made an example and included cell numbers - I hope that is easier to understand -  thank you.

Comment: It seems that Peter and Dave uses 15 and 22.5 holiday hours respectively, but there is no a value in column R for them... why?

Comment: Hi Akina, 


In my example, Peter worked 15 hours and used 15 hours holiday. 

I am trying to get column R to extract the holiday data only into it. 
Column R is the formula I am seeking help with so that I can do the below:


Cell R3 which would be Peters holiday, should extract the data from that row to show 15 hours. 

I would then use the same formula in each row for all staff. 


Thank you,

Comment: As a start try the formula `Rx=SUMIF(Bx:Nx,"hol",Cx:Ox)`... it must give correct result because C-E-..-O contains numbers (or are empty) and cannot be "hol".

Comment: That doesn't seem to work unfortunately - thank you though

Comment: I have reproduced your data, and this formula gives correct result... maybe you can share some example source file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This tricky method will help you to fix the issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter this Formula in Cell `K145` & fill down.

`=COUNTIF(B145:I145,$K$144)*7.5`

- Formula in cell `J145`, fill it down.

`=SUM(B145:H145)-K145`

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: I think that one was close, I got the column to add up to 45 which was the total hours holiday in there, 

The holiday won't always be 7.5 though so I need it to add up whatever is in the column. 

Thank you though

Comment: Does the function in K145 must be SUMIF, not COUNTIF?

Comment: Gald to help you @Chris,, if `7.5` is variable then use one cell to store the value & use with the formula, since  you  have used fixed value that's why I've used `7.5`,, formula can be changed as new situation.

Comment: @Akina,, using `Countif` is the tricky part of the solution,, which meets the situation's demand & solves the issue,, it's like out of the box method, may sounds as non conventional method ☺ Assume how longer `SUMIF`,, if Table has 20 or 30 Columns to test!!

Comment: Thank you for the help, that is great  :)

Comment: Glad to help you @Chris,, now you may up vote this also,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 1):

```
Rx=SUMIF(Bx:Nx,"hol",Cx:Ox)
```

or, if you want to hide zeros,

```
Rx=IF(0=SUMIF(Bx:Nx,"hol",Cx:Ox),"",SUMIF(Bx:Nx,"hol",Cx:Ox))
```

i.e. for R3 the formula is

```
=IF(0=SUMIF(B3:N3,"hol",C3:O3),"",SUMIF(B3:N3,"hol",C3:O3))
```

[image: example]

PS. Do not pay attention to commas in numbers - it is national formatting.

Comment: Absolute superstar - I definitely do not understand it but it sure works - amazing - thank you

Comment: @Chris It is simple. There are 2 arrays in args - B3:N3 and C3:O3. Each cell in 1st is "joined" to the cell in 2nd by its offset in a range - i.e. B3 in (1) is joined to C3 in (2), C3 in (1) is joined to (D3) and so on. Then the function takes each separate pair, checks the value in a cell from 1st range for equality to the given value "hol". If it is equal, then the value from joined cell in 2nd range is summed, if not equal, it is skipped. In complex only values adjacent to "hol" cells are summed.

Comment: I vaguely understand but still have much to learn - Thank you for taking the time to help  :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since you want to conditionally sum up rows rather than columns, the formula is a littly messy, but will produce the desired output. I am assuming from the example that "Dave" is row #6.

`=SUM(IF(B6="HOL";C6;0);IF(D6="HOL";E6;0);IF(F6="HOL";G6;0);IF(H6="HOL";I6;0);IF(J6="HOL";K6;0);IF(L6="HOL";M6;0);IF(N6="HOL";O6;0))`

There might be a more elegant solution, but SUMIF only supports continuous ranges.

Comment: Thank you, that formula doesn't seem to work - Think it  was along the right lines though

Comment: Weird, in which way did it not work? I basically copied your layout to create and test the formula.

Did you figure out another solution?

Comment: Says.... there's a problem with this formula. Not tryin to type a formula error message

Comment: No, not figured one out yet. Still trying 

 I did manage to get it to add up the entire lot via another suggestion but I think that was more luck than precise to be honest.

Comment: Have found a work around which is using part of your formula and some advice from another. I created a Monday to Friday skeleton rota. Used =SUMIF(E11,"hol",F11) for one cell and replicated this so it added in each day. I then created a total column and just hid the others. Thank you